# Is it possible to use JQuery to get the text between nested span tags?

Tags: jquery

I need to get the int value between the nested span tags and am not sure how to do this.

```
<div class="totals">
  <span class="pad">
    <span id="sum">100</span>
    <span id="sub">200</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I need to gain access to `100` and `200`. I have tried using `.parent('span').text()` but that isn't giving me anything back. I need to save these values in variables and use them elsewhere in my script. If this is possible, can someone show me how this can be done?

Comment: Quite unclear.. can you rephrase your question.?

Comment: `$('#sum').text()` and `$('#sub').text()`?

Comment: `$('#sum').text()` will return 100

Comment: that escalated quickly

Comment: `$.each($(".pad span"), function(el){ el.text(); })` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can look up the spans with `$(".totals .pad span")` and loop through them with `.each`, using `$(this).text()` within `each` to get the text:

```
$(".totals .pad span").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

...or you can address them by their `id` values and read the text directly:

```
console.log($("#sum").text()); // "100"
console.log($("#sub").text()); // "200"
```

If you need those values as numbers, you can use `parseInt(..., 10)` or `Number(...)` depending on your needs.

The [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) has info about the various jQuery calls above.

Comment: Thank you TJ. I appreciate the loop as well. I'm new to JQuery and would have probably needed help with that too. I'll credit you when the timer runs out

Answer (score 0):

You need a place to start from if you are literally just using `.parent('span').text()`. The following should work:

```
var sum = $('#sum').text();
var sub = $('#sub').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map` for this.

```
var spanvalues=$(".pad").find("span").map(function(){
 return $(this).text();
});
```

Then `spanvalues` will be an array which contains the text of `span` elements inside `.pad`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/208/)